# Search car parts by VIN

Tags: part-identification, parts, opel, vin

Is there a way to find out which vehicle part (from multiple part versions) do I need if I know vehicle VIN? I mean, for instance to see what ABS unit/s are compatible with an exact given vehicle?

I need this for Opel/Vauxhall Corsa C but I wonder if there is a general way to find out online for other marks too. I have not yet contacted an Opel dealer, trying to find out online first.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you require a vin based search over year/make/model/trim?

Comment: Not really actually, but the dealer usually asks me for it on part inquiry. VIN based search may be faster than model etc.

Comment: Well, I don't know what it's like in your area, but what I usually do is first just Google for "car parts search", and a bunch of salvage yard search web sites pop up (in the US a lot of salvage yards put their inventory in a central database), and I go down the list searching by make/model until I find a place near me with the part. If not, then I hit up individual stores (e.g. in my area there's Advanced Auto Parts, AutoZone, Pep Boys, etc.). The salvage searches are very specific, the vendor searches are good about finding off-brand compatible parts.

Comment: You can also call the dealer's parts department and e.g. ask what other years/models have that same part, and that will give you a wider range of things to search salvage yards for. I've never seen a salvage / vendor search go by VIN (although the dealers do, but their databases are a lot more specific and detailed). Oh and there's also online specialized wholesale vendors, like Honda Parts Guys, etc. You can probably find one for Opel.

Comment: The reason the dealership asks for a VIN is because their systems use the VIN to give an exact reference to your car. Their databases have all of that information in it and can pull it all by using the VIN. No guessing involved.